# How to reset knockout bindings in Jasmine test

Tags: knockout.js, binding, jasmine, reset

I'm trying to write test for knockout feature with jasmine as below and I'm getting following error:

*Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.*

```
describe("ThreeStepNavigationView", ()=> {
    var testSubject;
    var SmallNavigationStates = ['ribbon','expanded'];
    var ExtraSmallNavigationStates = ['collapsed','ribbon','expanded'];
    beforeEach(()=> {
        loadFixtures('SidebarAndSiteHeader.html');
        testSubject = new Mobile.Navigation.ThreeStepNavigation.View();
        ko.applyBindings(testSubject);
    });
    describe('When user clicks on navigation toggle button', ()=>{

    it('Should update state class name to the next state', ()=>{
        var button = $('#MobileMainNavLink');
        var currentScreenSize = Mobile.Helpers.getScreenSize();

        button.click();

        var classValue = $("#sidebar-wrapper").attr('class');
        if (currentScreenSize == 'ExtraSmall') {
            expect(classValue).toBe(ExtraSmallNavigationStates[1]);
        }
        if (currentScreenSize == 'Small') {
            expect(classValue).toBe(SmallNavigationStates[1]);
        }

    });

});
```

I did try resetting ko as but the result is the same.

```
 afterEach(()=>{
        ko.cleanNode($('#MobileMainNavLink')[0]);
        ko.cleanNode($('#sidebar-wrapper')[0]);
    });
```

Based on ko documentation cleanNode is an internal function and is not part of the API.

I'm using ko 3.2 and jasmine 1.5

Comment: Looks like KO is being bound more than once. I can only guess this is occurring during the loadfixtures step or during the instantiation of the view. Try commenting out `ko.applyBindings(testSubject);`.

Comment: ...plus your test is kind of strange in that it appears to have a different assertion based on the screen size at the time of running the test, which is probably not a great idea (unless I am missing something).

Comment: tried `removeNode ` which is similar to `cleanNode`(removes node from DOM)

Answer (score 0):

Your not explicitly applying your bindings to a node. I believe this will therefore apply to your **document.body**. Which explains your error as your not cleaning the body.

> ko.applyBindings(testSubject);

Ref: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

> In case you’re wondering what the parameters to ko.applyBindings do,
>
> The first parameter says what view model object you want to use with
>   the declarative bindings it activates
>
> Optionally, you can pass a second parameter to define which part of
>   the document you want to search for data-bind attributes. For example,
>   ko.applyBindings(myViewModel,
>   document.getElementById('someElementId')). This restricts the
>   activation to the element with ID someElementId and its descendants,
>   which is useful if you want to have multiple view models and associate
>   each with a different region of the page.

Useful Function:

```
// Checks if Element has Already been Bound (Stops Errors Occuring if already bound as element can't be bound multiple times)
var isBound = function (id) {
    if (document.getElementById(id) != null)
        return !!ko.dataFor(document.getElementById(id));
    else
        return false;
};
```

Answer:

```
testSubject = new Mobile.Navigation.ThreeStepNavigation.View();
if (isBound("parent-container"))
    ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById('parent-container'));
ko.applyBindings(testSubject, document.getElementById("parent-container"));
```