# How can you reset Knockout for each Jasmine test?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js, jasmine

I have some feature tests that run with a fixture (loaded with jasmine-jquery) that has some Knockout bindings in the HTML. At the begin of each test I want to start with a viewModel in its initial state.

If I call applyBindings() in the beforeEach() with a new instance of the viewModel I get this error from Knockout

> Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

If I try to revert the properties of the existing viewModel to match its initial state I still get an error. I believe this is because the fixture's HTML is removed after each test - this probably breaks the bindings?

I've also tried a suggestion that [came up when Googling](http://forums.asp.net/t/1825292.aspx?Rebinding%20Problem%20with%20Jquery%20knockout%20js%20with%20MVC) which was to use the cleanNode function in Knockout. This isn't part of the API (it only designed to be used by Knockout internally) and no matter what I tried it didn't resolve the issue.

It feels like I'm taking the wrong approach to this. **tl;dr; How does everybody else test Knockout with Jasmine?**

Thanks for any help

Comment: why are you asking similar questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247822/how-to-reset-knockout-bindings-in-jasmin-test just edit one of them if you have more to add and delete the other one.

Comment: The other question was very specific. This is a more open question about patterns for testing Knockout.

Comment: Yes, the back story is the same for both. But I'm asking two different questions and expecting different answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally append an element in `beforeEach`, apply bindings to that element, and `ko.removeNode` on it in `afterEach`. Something like:

```
            var fixture;

            beforeEach(function() {
                fixture = document.createElement("div");
                document.body.appendChild(fixture);
            });

            afterEach(function() {
                ko.removeNode(fixture);
            });
```

Then use `fixture` as the second argument to any applyBindings calls like: `ko.applyBindings(myTestViewModel, fixture);`

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was changing my js to check for jasmine e.g.:

```
if (!window.jasmine)
   ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: This looks like you're modifying your production code to fix your tests? Unless I've missed something the solution RP Niemeyer suggested is much better.

Comment: I think I'm missing something but when I tried RP Niemeyer's solution it didn't work. Where should ko.applyBindings(myTestViewModel, fixture) live because my applyBindings only lives in the js file with the viewmodel.